# Почему код такого формата выводит все элементы списка без скобок и запятых?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print(*List) #где List это любой список
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за оформление

Answer (score 1):

Звёздочка - это операция [распаковки](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), превращающая список в аргументы функции `print`.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
print(*a)
```

эквивалентно

```
print(1, 2, 3)
```